# Conditionnally change color on multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angular js.

I have two list:

- selectedChosenSpecialites
- selectedMandatorySpecialites

The list of selectedSpecialites is displayed in a multiselect dropdown. By double-click on one of them,  the speciality is added to the selectedMandatorySpecialiltes (or removed).

If an item of selectedSpecialites is in the list of selectedMandatorySpecialites, I want it to appear in another color (let's say red).

However, I don't find how to apply a conditional color style in a multiselect dropdown after an user double-click.

Could you help me?

Here is the code for the multiselect:

```
 <select class="form-control" size="60" id="field_specialite" multiple name="specialite" ng- 
 dblclick="vm.addOrRemoveSpecialiteObligatoire(vm.selectedChosenSpecialites)"  ng- 
  model="vm.selectedChosenSpecialites"
 ng-options="specialite as specialite.libelle for specialite in 
 vm.selectedSpecialites|orderBy:'libelle' track by specialite.id">
  </select>
```

Thanks

Comment: why not use a custom component?

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

`selects` (and other input types) are rendered in an OS specific manner. You have very little control over them. The comment above about using a "custom component" just means create your own component that renders a list of items in a way that multiple are selectable - i.e. don't use a `select`.

Look at this multi-select, for instance: https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples

Comment: The thing is that this kind of select is used throughout the app I'm working on. I can't change all select and the display will be strange if I use another one. There is no way to take control on the one I showed you?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select - scroll down to `Styling with CSS` and you'll see what I mean, the paragraph starts with `The <select> element is notoriously difficult to style productively with CSS.` If it's critical for you to style this component, then you most likely have no choice but to implement a custom one.

Comment: ok thanks. I guess I have no choice. Do you know about sample code with a custom select that looks like this kind of select component?

Comment: Component frameworks are your friend. Alternatively, don't shy away from it and think that the select input is somehow "special" - it's a list of strings that you can click on and toggle selection. One (of many) is [ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect-checkbox)